# insert different value on different row

Tags: jquery

It is possible insert different value to different row table? when add row and insert item, the 1st row item will change same like 2nd row item.

```
var count = $(".itemRow").length;
$(document).on("click", "#addRows", function () {
    count++;
    var htmlRows = "";
    htmlRows += "<tr>";
    htmlRows += '<td><input class="itemRow" type="checkbox"></td>';
    htmlRows +=
        '<td><div style="display: flex;"><input style="width:60%; margin-top:0.5%; margin-left:0.5%" type="text" name="productName[]" id="productName_'+ count +'" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">&nbsp <p class="item-select items" style="padding-top:1%;"> or <a href="#" data-target="#myModal">select a product</a></p></div></td>';
    htmlRows +=
        '<td><input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity_' +
        count +
        '" class="form-control quantity" autocomplete="off"></td>';
    htmlRows +=
        '<td><input type="number" name="price" id="price_' +
        count +
        '" class="form-control price" autocomplete="off"></td>';
    htmlRows +=
        '<td><input type="number" name="total" id="total_' +
        count +
        '" class="form-control total" autocomplete="off"></td>';
    htmlRows += "</tr>";
    $("#invoiceItem").append(htmlRows);
});
```

```
$(document).on("click", "#modal", function (){
        var productName = $("#productname").val();
        var nameProduct = productName.split('||')[0];
        var pPrice = pr`your text`oductName.split('||')[1];
        $("[id^=productName_]").val(nameProduct);
        $("[id^=price_]").val(pPrice);
    });
```

[1st row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLZ8E.png)

[when add 2nd row and insert item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZxOQ.png)

[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIAFo.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("[id^=productName_]").val(nameProduct);` this part of your code replaces the entire elements instead of just one.

Modifying this line to `$("#productName_" + count ).val(nameProduct);` would solve your issue.